# Android Development: Swipe up to refresh instead of swipe down with compose

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

I have a fully implemented working swipe to refresh functionality using google's
[Modifier.pullRefresh()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/pullrefresh/package-summary) api

but it works by swiping down and i want to swipe up to refresh (for things like loading new messages in a chat for example). how do i do that?

[image: image of pullrefreshindicator popping from the bottom of the screen]

here's my implementation of swipe down to refresh (again, it works perfectly):

```
    var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    fun refresh() = coroutineScope.launch {
        if (database != null){
            refreshing = true
            // things to load or network actions here
            refreshing = false
        }
    }
    val refreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, ::refresh)
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        refresh()
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pullRefresh(refreshState)
       ){
                 PullRefreshIndicator(
                      refreshing, 
                      refreshState,    
                      Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter), contentColor = NuttyBrown)

        }
```

**I'm using Kotlin, Jetpack compose, with Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2**

Comment: It does not look like this is possible "out of the box". However, `pullRefresh()` is very small, mostly delegating to a `PullRefreshNestedScrollConnection` private class. That is where the up/down logic resides. It feels like you could clone `PullRefreshNestedScrollConnection`, invert the behavior, and create a `pullFromBottomRefresh()` modifier that uses it.